# Mysqli prepared statements SUM column value

Tags: php, mysqli, sum, prepared-statement

I am trying to sum the values from a column using mysqli prepared statement with the code below but is not working. Does anyone can help me pointing what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(col) as total FROM tb_a WHERE user=?");

$stmt2->bind_param("s", $user);
$stmt2->execute();
$op_row = $stmt2->fetch_assoc();

echo $op_row['total'];
```

Comment: Gonna need to know what you mean by "not working". Is it returning an error? A row? Anything?

Comment: Sorry!! the error is "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()"

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the SUM and everything to do with the PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andrew I didn't fix it yet. But I'll try to find what is happening

Comment: @VictorDallecio Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
$user = "Larry"; // example

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(col) FROM tb_a WHERE user=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($total);

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo $total;
```

or

```
$user = "Robert"; // example

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(col) FROM tb_a WHERE user=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($total);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo $total;

}
```

Comment: @VictorDallecio You're welcome Victor. You can use either one is fine. The one with `while ($stmt->fetch())` you don't really need though, thought I would include that also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(col) as total FROM tb_a WHERE user=?");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $user);
$stmt2->execute();
$res = $stmt2->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

The prepared statement object do not have a fetch_assoc() method so you should first use get_result() and the result of that has a fetch_assoc()

Comment: You should implementing OP's query instead `("SELECT SUM(col) as total FROM tb_a WHERE user=?")`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it! @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$conn = new mysqli;
$sum = "SELECT SUM(col) as total FROM tb_a WHERE user=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sum);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
$sum= $stmt->execute();
```